# Read all standard input into a Java byte array

Tags: java, unix, stdin

What's the simplest way in modern Java (using only the standard libraries) to read *all of* standard input until EOF into a byte array, preferably without having to provide that array oneself? The stdin data is binary stuff and doesn't come from a file.

I.e. something like Ruby's

```
foo = $stdin.read
```

The only partial solution I could think of was along the lines of

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1000000];
int b;
int i = 0;

while (true) {
    b = System.in.read();
    if (b == -1)
        break;
    buf[i++] = (byte) b;
}

byte[] foo[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, 0, i);
```

... but that seems bizarrely verbose even for Java, and uses a fixed size buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and its [`ByteStreams.toByteArray`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)) method:

```
byte[] data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(System.in);
```

Without using any 3rd party libraries, I'd use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and a temporary buffer:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];

int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = System.in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

... possibly encapsulating that in a method accepting an `InputStream`, which would then be basically equivalent to `ByteStreams.toByteArray` anyway...

Comment: Thanks. Pretty crazy that something like the Guava solution is not in the mainline stdlib.

Comment: The reason it's not is because the Java authors attempt to discourage reading stuff into byte arrays (which will break with sufficiently large data) when it could/should be processed as a stream instead (which can handle unlimited amounts of data).

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading from a file, [Files.readAllBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) is the way to do it.

Otherwise, I'd use a ByteBuffer:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000000);
ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(System.in);
while (channel.read(buf) >= 0)
    ;
buf.flip();
byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOf(buf.array(), buf.limit());
```

Comment: This is wrong as you are not checking for buf.hasRemaining()

Comment: Actually, checking hasRemaining() is a bad idea.  The goal is to read all the bytes, so we don't want to silently stop reading just because we hit the end of the buffer.  An exception is better than treating truncated data as if it were complete data.  I assumed a max size of 1000000 because the OP seems comfortable with that assumption.